How can I do a local and remote HMAC comparison in an Azure Workflow
I have a C# script embedded in an 'Execute CSharp Script Code' object on an Azure workflow.
This takes an external HMAC key passed in the header and some JSON text in the body as input and needs to calculate a new HMAC locally and compare the two for authenticity.
My HMAC strings aren't matching because the output body type is as shown below when the original is formatted.
My testing script:
// Add the required libraries
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.Scripting"
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.Scripting;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// Executes the inline csharp code.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The workflow context.</param>
/// <remarks> This is the entry-point to your code. The function signature should remain unchanged.</remarks>
public static async Task<Results> Run(WorkflowContext context, ILogger log)
{
  //String Variables (for clarity)
  string compare = string.Empty;
  string _origonalMessage = string.Empty;
  string _origonalHmac = string.Empty;
  string _calculatedHmac = string.Empty;

  ////Define the trigger output.
  var triggerOutputs = (await context.GetTriggerResults().ConfigureAwait(false)).Outputs;

  ////Set the local HMAC key from the Azure Key Vault.
  string secretKey = "HMAC-GG-TEST"; // <-- Temporary for testing.
  //I need to make a key vault get the secret from this.
  //Maybe something like: var secretKeysTEST = await client.GetSecretAsync(HMAC);
  
  ////Set the whole JSON body text  from the trigger.
  var origonalMessage = triggerOutputs["body"].ToString();
  _origonalMessage = origonalMessage;

  ////Set the remote HMAC encrypted text from the Azure header. (needs to be the input header)
  var receievedHmac = triggerOutputs?["headers"]?["HMACEncripted"]?.ToString();
  _origonalHmac = receievedHmac;

  ////Encrypt the body text with the local HMAC key and compare with the remote Encrypted text.
  //convert key and message to byte arrays
  byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
  byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(origonalMessage);

  //Create an HMAC SHA256 instance with the local key
  using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
    {
        //Compute the HMAC and convert it to a string
        byte[] hashBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        var localHmac = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    _calculatedHmac = localHmac;
  }

  //Compare the computed HMAC with the received HMAC
  string testString = "GAURAV";
  if (_calculatedHmac.Equals(receievedHmac, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  {
    compare = "Match";
  }
  else
  {
    compare = "noMatch:  Calc=" + _calculatedHmac + "  Orig=" + _origonalHmac + "  Body=" + _origonalMessage;
;
  }


  return new Results
  {
    Message = compare 
  };
}

public class Results
{
  public string Message {get; set;}
}

Output from the script:
{
  "body": {
    "message": "noMatch: Calc=62c72a210402ffc1cefed5547192fd14e44ef1dfdc012f3279940ab5f35105b8
                         Orig=af9d5fe5216e4a3c731cc864ddc0dba66ae22b68605678fd2a3c381dc5c72025
                         Body={\r\n  \"id\": 13,\r\n  \"baseprofile\": {\r\n    \"id\": 3,\r\n    \"value\": \"Accountant\",\r\n    \"profile\": \"https://api.icims.com/customers/1234/jobs/3/\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"associatedprofile\": {\r\n    \"id\": 5,\r\n    \"value\": \"JohnSmith\",\r\n    \"profile\": \"https://api.icims.com/customers/1234/people/5/\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"status\": {\r\n    \"id\": \"D5432\",\r\n    \"value\": \"InterviewScheduled\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"source\": \"iCIMS.com\",\r\n  \"sourcename\": \"Internal\"\r\n}"
  }
}

Origonal formated JSON is like this:
{
    "id": 13,
    "baseprofile": {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "Accountant",
        "profile": "https://api.icims.com/customers/1234/jobs/3/"
    },
    "associatedprofile": {
        "id": 5,
        "value": "JohnSmith",
        "profile": "https://api.icims.com/customers/1234/people/5/"
    },
    "status": {
        "id": "D5432",
        "value": "InterviewScheduled"
    },
    "source": "iCIMS.com",
    "sourcename": "Internal"
}

So, how do you compare the local and remote HMAC strings specifically in an Azure Workflow ‘CSharp Script Code’ object calculated on the input body text, whilst preserving the formatting? When looking at the input and output JSON text through Postman the formatting is preserved and the text looks the same.
Any help would be appreciated.

It looks like json is containing escaping characters

It looks like logic app is formatting the request body automatically whether you reformat it or not. Due to this, hmac is not getting generated correctly but the code you are using is correct.
Also Execute CSharp Script Code action is in preview phase, so its just giving a generic error every time the code fails which is difficult to troubleshoot the error.
If you will create an Azure function and then execute, it will give you correct hmac but if you call the function from the logic app then again you will start getting the incorrect hmac due to formatting issue.
So, I would recommend you to use Azure function which fulfils your requirement. I am using below code to calculate hmac.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace _79275662
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("CalculateHMAC")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Calculating HMAC for the provided JSON body.");
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            string secretKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HMAC_SECRET_KEY");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secretKey))
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("HMAC secret key is not configured.");
            }
            
            string calculatedHMAC;
            try
            {
                byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
                byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);

                using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
                {
                    byte[] hashBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
                    calculatedHMAC = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError($"Error calculating HMAC: {ex.Message}");
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }

            return new OkObjectResult(new { hmac = calculatedHMAC });
        }
    }
}

This gives me expected response in Azure function app.

